# Use coffeescript or javascript in rails form to grab model attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I am working on a Rails app and need some help with coffeescript which I'm not very good at.

I have a form with a field called `location_id` using a collection in Rails.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :location_id, Region.order(:area), :active_locations, :area, :id, :location_name_with_address, {include_blank: true}, class: 'select' %>
```

On the `Location` model there is a column named `modifier` which holds a value.  Within my form I need to be able to grab the `modifier` value to evaluate it client-side to display/hide a div.

I'm starting to write my coffeescript and am able to get the `id` of the `Location` like this

`$('#call_location_id').val()`

But what I'm unsure of how to do is, how do I grab that `id` of the location, and evaluate the model attribute `modifier`?  I'm not sure how to grab it on the client side.

I've googled and have read a lot of coffeescript snippets but can't seem to find the right direction to take.

I just need a bump in the right path so I can figure the rest out on my own.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the rendered HTML?

Comment: @max Do you want a screenshot or the actual html that is spit out from Chrome inspector?

Comment: Hmm, I gave it a bit of thought. Either you send a JSON ajax request to `/locations/:id` which would render the details of the location.

Comment: Or you create your own version of grouped_collection_select which includes `location.modifier` as a data attribute on the option element. You can get the select option by listening for the change event and using `$(this).children("option:selected");` in the event handler.

Comment: The ajax approach is most likely the easiest but might have a slight delay.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following on how to make my own version of grouped_collection_select.  I could overwrite the method in Rails internals but this seems like something I could still handle client side, just not sure how the backend connects to the front end.

Comment: Either through what is present in the document or through ajax.

Comment: Ok, I'll dig a bit on my own, but will continue to monitor this thread for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with a select statement and mapping out the locations while passing data attributes for me to grab via coffeescript.

```
<%= f.select :location_id, grouped_options_for_select(Region.order(:area).map{ |group| [group.area, group.locations.order('location_name asc').map{ |o| [o.location_name, o.id, {'data-modifier'=>o.location_modifier, 'data-name'=> o.location_name}] } ] }, f.object.transfer_from_id), {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'} %>
```